# What is the correct way to convert an int array to string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, type-conversion

I was thinking what the best way would be to convert a integer array, for example

`int array[] = {0x53,0x74,0x61,0x63,0x6B,0x4F,0x76,0x65,0x72,0x66,0x6C,0x6F,0x77,0x00}`

to a string, the above integer array is the equivalent of:

`int array[] = {'S','t','a','c','k','O','v','e','r','f','l','o','w',0}`

so a resulting string would be

`std::string so("StackOverflow");`

I was thinking of looping through eacht element with foreach and adding it to the string by casting it to `char`, but I'm wondering if there are cleaner / faster / neater ways to do this?

Comment: I think you meant `char array[]`, not `int array[]`.

Comment: @barakmanos Why? Ints can store hex values too.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see the "equivalent" there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `int` is implicitly convertible to `char`, you don't need any casts. All standard containers have constructors that take a pair of iterators, so you can pass the beginning and the end of the array:

```
std::string so( std::begin(array), std::end(array) );
```

This might not be any faster than a manual loop, but I think it fits the criteria of neater and cleaner.

There's a clean way to do the same with array of pointers, too. Use [Boost Indirect Iterator:](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html)

```
#include <boost/iterator/indirect_iterator.hpp>

std::string s (
    boost::make_indirect_iterator(std::begin(array)),
    boost::make_indirect_iterator(std::end(array)) );
```

One more thing I just noticed - you don't need a 0 in the int array just to mark the end of a string. `std::end` will deduce the size of the array and 0 will actualy end up in the resulting string.

Comment: @Gizmo `std::string so(array,array+length)` should work - the end iterator is 1 past usable data, in this case `array+length` should point to `0x00` value in array;

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a (slightly) faster way, then you can do:

```
char str[sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)];

for (int i=0; i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array); i++)
    str[i] = (char)array[i];

std::string so(str);
```

This will "save you" the repeated call to `std::string::operator+=`...